# Bash script does not run VNC-viewer command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vnc, udev

So im trying to open a VNC client when a Udev rule triggers, the rules works and the script is executed too but the command isn't.

Here is the Bash script

```
    #!/bin/bash
sudo -u term402 touch /home/term402/scripts/whoami
sudo -u term402 echo $(date) >> /home/term402/scripts/whoami
sudo -u term402 whoami >> /home/term402/scripts/whoami
sudo -u term402 echo "_________________________________________" >> /home/term402/scripts/whoami
sudo -u term402 /usr/bin/vncviewer -viewonly -passwd /home/term402/.vnc/passwd <ip>
```

When i run the Script in the Terminal it works as it should.

Comment: Since i`vncviewer` is a GUI program, perhaps it needs to know the `DISPLAY` (which would not normally be part of the udev environment)?

Comment: You mean the display of the vnc server of the device which is runnung the viewer?

Comment: No, I mean the local display on which you expect `vncviewer` to open

Comment: How do i tell the script on which screen vncviewer is supposed to run?

Comment: Find out what it's set to in the interactive shell (where the script works) using `echo $DISPLAY` or `printenv` for example, and then try (for example) `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/vncviewer`. You might want to consider removing all the `sudo -u` commands from *within* the script and running the whole thing with `sudo -u`